# Update a specific event on google recurring event without missing it's repeat info in Java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I created a recurring event using google calendar api for Java and I try to do patch to one of its event instance by changing only its description value, but when I finished doing that I can't see the repeat check button anymore in my google calendar. Can anyone tell me how to update one specific event instance on recurring event without losing its repeat check button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The exact same thing happens when you edit the description of an event and say "Only this instance" from the calendar web UI. I don't think there is currently a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about to do the "all-following" events update on existing recurrence events using the api in Java?